# Date preprocessor like ___DATE___ in Xcode

Tags: xcode

How to have a string of  `___DATE___` for compile date version in an application?

Comment: I guess running /bin/cpp on your code prior to compilation is out?

Comment: i was using the one from the template and it as extra underscore

Answer (score 0):

okay found it

```
__DATE__
```

with less underscore.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", __DATE__]
```

and then you have your compile date version.